# Adjust Footer Position Based On Content

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to adjust the position of the footer based on the content on the page. If I have very little content on the page, then I need the footer to be displayed after the content, and if I have more content on the page, I want to display the footer at the bottom of window.

I have made a demo: here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-59tthr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

When the page has more content, the footer sticks to the bottom of page which is good but if I toggle the content it is still in same position.

Is it possible to set the footer exactly after the content?

Answer (score 0):

**This could help**

I check this in your demo it's work fine.

```
.MainWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px; /* this will be the height of your footer */
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

If your `footer` height is bigger then try to add `padding-bottom` value using `js`.

Comment: Thanks your answer gave me another idea.I have updated the demo.This is what i exactly needed

Comment: @abhilashreddy,  Then what you exactly need ??

Comment: I got the solution brother,if you look here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-59tthr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html when the page has large content i want the footer to be visible always which is working fine.If the content is small then footer should be displayed in the position where content is finished.

Comment: Ok , Brother . @abhilashreddy